# Python 3 unicode codec error binding mousewheel in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Using Python 3.6/tkinter on MacOS, I created a frame within a canvas and bound a scrollbar to it. This all works fine. The problem is when I try to snag MouseWheel events when the cursor is in the scrollable frame. I set up a binding:

```
main_window.bind("<MouseWheel>",on_mousewheel)
```

and created a short dummy event handler:

```
def on_mousewheel(event):
    print(event.delta)
```

Every time I use the scroll wheel, Python responds with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Gary/IPPS/opendb.py", line 160, in <module>
    main_window.mainloop()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1277, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

def on_main_window_resize(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))

def on_mousewheel(event):
    print(event.delta)

main_window = Tk()
main_window.bind("<MouseWheel>",on_mousewheel)
canvas = Canvas(main_window, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
cust_scroll = Scrollbar(main_window, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
cust_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y, expand=NO)
cust_list = Frame(canvas)
canvas['yscrollcommand'] = cust_scroll.set
canvas.bind('<Configure>', on_main_window_resize)
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=cust_list, anchor=NW)
main_window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
main_window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

memberbuttons = list();
for member in range(1,20):
    memberbutton = Button(cust_list, text="BUTTON", justify=LEFT, pady=2)
    memberbutton.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
main_window.mainloop()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, _Complete_, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In its current state, the code you've provided is incomplete to reproduce that error.

Comment: I've added the code, @Nae. Sorry about that.

Comment: I can't reproduce the same error still. Only that mousewheel does nothing w/o any errors.

Comment: What do you get with `print(repr(event.delta))` or `print(type(event.delta))`?

Comment: The first "tick" of the mouse wheel works fine, displaying 1 or -1 depending on the direction of movement (I didn't notice this before, as I was just spinning the wheel). The second movement of the mouse wheel causes the Unicode error as shown, no matter what the "print()" contains. I tried it with just `print("on_mousewheel")` (not referencing event.delta at all), and it fails with the Unicode error immediately.

Comment: @GaryR. this is extremely strange. I can't reproduce this either, so I'm just shooting in the dark here: Try binding to the canvas instead of the root window: `canvas.bind("<MouseWheel>",on_mousewheel)`

Comment: @Novel, binding it to the canvas doesn't help, even when not referencing event.delta. Is this a Mac problem, perhaps? I'm using the tkinter library that automatically installed with Python 3.6, so it wouldn't be a version mismatch.

Comment: Another shot in the dark: Add `return "break"` to the on_mousewheel function.

Comment: Adding `return "break"` doesn't change anything. Strangely, though, if I add the `return "break"` and remove the `print(event.delta)`, then I get the Unicode error the first time I attempt to scroll down, but not until the second time I attempt to scroll up. This is confusing the heck out of me.

Comment: Can you provide the actual error message from this very code snippet that you've provided?

Comment: The code works as shown on Python 3.6 with Windows 10 as well and returns an integer value (-120 or 120 in my case).  What does `print(ascii(event.delta))` display?

Comment: Thank you all for the help and suggestions, but I've given up on tkinter and switched to wxPython, which seems to be working *much* more smoothly for me.

Comment: I got the same error by accident and I can also reproduce the error with the code provided. Python 3.6.5 on a macOS 10.13.4. Seems like a bug in the tkinter library.

Comment: Thank you, felixblade! I'm glad to hear it was reproducible for someone else.

Comment: It's so strange. I have the same problem here and don't know how to solve..

Answer (score 0):

I found some references online useful to grasp the problem, it seems to happen on an older version of ActiveTcl (8.5.x).

[Inertial scrolling in Mac OS X with Tkinter and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995969/inertial-scrolling-in-mac-os-x-with-tkinter-and-python)

[nltk/nltk on Github - OS X: downloader GUI crashes in Python 3 when mouse wheel is used for scrolling](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/696)

The **solution** is to *upgrade* your version of *ActiveTlc* to `>=8.6` and you can do this in two ways:

- manually
- installing the latest version of Python 3.7.1 via the binary package on [Python Release 3.7.1](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-371/)