# UnicodeDecodeError during plot.show() in python virtual environment

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, tkinter

Hi I'm currently trying to experiment with deep learning with python in my Mac terminal. So far, what I did was create a virtual environment and installed all the requirements needed such as Tensorflow, Keras and the libraries (one of them is `matplotlib` which is related to the problem). My python version is **3.7**.

So when I try to execute my code below, I got this following error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "deepLearning.py", line 17,
>   in 
>       plt.show()
>   File "/Users/zaki/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py",
>   line 253, in show
>       return _show(*args, **kw)
>   File "/Users/zaki/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py",
>   line 3266, in show
>       cls.mainloop()
>   File "/Users/zaki/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py",
>   line 1037, in mainloop
>       Tk.mainloop()
>   File"/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py",
>   line 557, in mainloop
>       _default_root.tk.mainloop(n)
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position
>   0: invalid start byte

```
from __future__ import print_function
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop #pillow, from PIL import image, Opencv

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10 # 0,1,2,3...10
epochs = 20

(x_train, y_train), (x_test,y_test) = mnist.load_data()

plt.imshow(x_train[1]) # this is to show the image
plt.show()
```

Comment: This seems to be an issue with tkinter on macOs, but probably with some particular combination of tcl, tk and python.  Here are two similar examples I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085420/python-3-unicode-codec-error-binding-mousewheel-in-tkinter  and https://github.com/Qirky/FoxDot/issues/32.  Not much help to you but maybe someone more knowledgeable about tkinter might have some ideas.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks...at least I can try something

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when calling `plt.show()`
I managed to workaround with:

```
while True:
  try:
    plt.show()
    break
  except UnicodeDecodeError:
    continue
```